# ionic3: lazy loading - not find module:Error: Cannot find module '../pages/Acompont/Acompont.module'

Tags: ionic3, lazy-evaluation

```
Env:
Ionic Framework: 3.7.0
Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.0
Angular Core: 4.4.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.4.3
Node: 6.9.2
OS Platform: OS X El Capitan
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Commands ran:

```
ionic start demo super
cd demo
npm install
ionic serve
```

[image]